# Can I override Hashsets way of determine duplicate?

Tags: java, json, hashset

Im using Hashset that stores JSONObjects.
I know hashset uses both hashCode() and equals method to determine if the object is duplicate.

After checking i can see that the same JSONObject returns 2 different hascodes even tho equals() and similar() returns true, which basically means JSONObject didnt override the hashcode() properly.

I am aware that if ill use libs like Gson or Jackson i would probably solve this issue, but my code is deeply invested in using JSONObject and refactor all of it to use one of those libs will take 2 much time.

My question - is there a way to set an hashSet way of deciding duplicates?

something like

```
HashSet<JSONObject> hs = new HashSet();
hs.setDuplicateStrategy((o1, o2) => { o1.similar(o2)});
```

any other solutions will be welcome

Comment: Can you use a `Set<JSONObject> hs = new TreeSet<>(jsonObjectComparable);`?

Comment: This will mean ill have to wrap the JSONObject in my own object that implements Comparable, am i right?

Comment: I didnt managed to implement what you wrote, what does "jsonObjectComparable" mean in your code? is it a new object that implements comparable, and thats an instance of it? I would appreciate if you farther explain your solution

Comment: Sorry I meant a `Comparator<JSONObject>` which allows you to specific how these objects are compared and when they are equal.

Comment: I dont know if thats exactly what you meant but i wrote an answer to show what i managed to do and works, feel free to comment anything you think is wrong with my solution, ill accept it as an answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't extend `JSONObject` and `HashSet` doesn't support alternative hashing providers (like `TreeSet` does with comparators), the simple solution is to wrap it  in a class that does implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` properly.

Or use a different `Set` implementation (e.g. `TreeSet`).

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterLawrey suggested in the comments.

I figured out a way to write a TreeSet in a way to actually set its logical comparable method

```
Set<JSONObject> treeSet = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
                            int intRes = 0;
                            if(!o1.similar(o2)){
                                intRes = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
                            }
                            return intRes;
                        });
```

The Math.random part is to ensure that if the objects arent the same we wont end up with a very imbalanced tree as all the none identical objects will be in the same side of the tree

Comment: Having a comparator that relies on random is a Very Bad Idea™. Just choose a consistent order instead. The re-balancing of the internal tree of `TreeSet` is independent of the comparator results, but you can temporarily "lose" half your tree with this strategy. *TL;DR * **the random bit of this is wrong, it breaks the contract of `Comparator` and breaks `TreeSet`**.

Comment: But i have no logical way to determined which one is bigger, hence the alternative is to just return 1; at all times they are not equal, that way the tree will have all the items on the same side

Comment: That thing about the tree is just simply not true. I don't even know where you got it from, but I urge you to read up on [self-balancing trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). And there is a logical way to determine which one's bigger, just compare their `hashCode()`s. (Always returning `1` is just as bad as returning a random number by the way.)